# jquery fancybox not opening second time

Tags: jquery

Im using jquery fancy box version 2.1.4 for data preview when i first time when i click im able to see the preview,second time it is not opening the preview page eventhough id is passing .

> http://jsfiddle.net/9aW9N/

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fancybox2.1.4/jquery.fancybox.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox2.1.4/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>
<script>
/* <![CDATA[ */
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.preview').on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      cache: true,
      url: this.href, 
      data: $("#form1").serializeArray(),
      success: function (data) {

        $.fancybox(data, {

          fitToView: false,
          width: 905,
          height: 505,
          autoSize: false,
          overlayShow   :   true,
          closeClick: false,
          openEffect: 'none',
          closeEffect: 'none'
        }); // fancybox
      } // success
    }); // ajax
  }); // on
}); // ready
/* ]]> */
</script>
</head>
<form name="name" id="form1" method="post"
    enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="innerbox" >
<div class="formbox_in" style="float: left;"><label>File Name :</label>
<input type="file" value="" name="id> <input type="hidden"
    name="id" value="1" id="id"> <a class="preview" href="data.php"
    id="preview">Preview </a></div>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you create a fiddle.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9aW9N/